# Calculate average between two columns using Pig

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I've a file with three columns representing a date and a min/max temperature value.

```
01012010    4.5    15.9
```

I need to calculate, for each day, the average.
This seems pretty easy to do with a UDF but I would like to know if there's a way to do it without it.

I managed to achieve something like this (concatenating the temperatures and then flattening them) but it seems really too complex to me:

```
table          = LOAD 'e7/temp.csv' USING PigStorage('\t') as (day:chararray, min:float, max:float);
day_group      = FOREACH table GENERATE day, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE( CONCAT(CONCAT( (chararray)min, ','), (chararray)max) )) as minMax;
day_group_cast = FOREACH day_group GENERATE day, (float) minMax as minMax;
day_mean_group = GROUP day_group_cast BY day;
day_mean       = FOREACH day_mean_group GENERATE group as day, AVG(day_group_cast.minMax) as minMax;
```

Comment: Will you have more than one record for a day or its just a single record for a given day ? If its the later case, Why not compute avg directly (min+max)/2 ?

Comment: @MuraliRao This is why I shouldn't do this kind of exercise at 6:30am.. yep, it's the later case and it obviously works. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Enrichman comments, below snippet would be suffice to achieve the objective.

```
temp_data =  LOAD 'temp.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (day:chararray, min:float, max:float);
req_stats = FOREACH temp_data GENERATE day, (min+max)/2 AS avg_temp;
```